# Given $U \times V=\langle -4,-2,-1 \rangle$, find $(U-3V) \times (U+2V)$

Tags: calculus, cross-product

I am studying cross products and ran into trouble with this question. $U$ and $V$ are vectors, the $\times$ stands for the cross product. Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit: I assume I need to use the properties of the cross product in some way but I am not sure which ones to use. Specifically, I am confused as to how I am supposed to solve the interior equations of $(U-3v)$ and $(U+2V)$ without ever having been giving their original vectors. To my knowledge, it's not really possible to reverse the cross product if you are not given (at least 1 of) the original vectors used.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like a straightfoward calculation using $U\times U=V\times V=0$ and $V\times U=-U\times V$.

Comment: Using previous comment, final result is $5(U\times V)$.

Comment: @okayokay  My first comment shows basic properties of cross products, which is all you need.

Comment: The relevant facts that haven't yet been mentioned are $(A+B)\times C = A\times C + B\times C$ and $(xD)\times E = x(D\times E)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can just use the facts that,

$V×V=0$, $U×U=0$ and $U×V=-V×U$

So,

$(U-3V)×(U+2V)$

$=U×(U+2V)-3V×(U+2V)$

$=U×U+2(U×V)-3(V×U)-6(V×V)$

$=2\langle -4,-2,-1\rangle+3\langle -4,-2,-1\rangle$

$=\langle -20,-10,-5\rangle$